# Issue in text data conversion into numerical format

Tags: machine-learning, hpcc-ecl, hpcc

I'm trying to convert a sentence of text that is present in my dataset into a numerical format so that it can be an input to my ML model.

I feel it a bit difficult to understand TextVectors in ECL https://hpccsystems.com/resources/textvectors-machine-learning-for-textual-data/ Can anyone provide more details regarding this concept, if any examples are available please share the documents.

Comment: What kind of text?

Comment: Yes, please provide an example of the type of text you need to parse and what you expect to get as a result.